# Windows 10 - Disable inertial scrolling

Tags: windows-10, scrolling

I just restarted my laptop after it booted I noticed scrolling behavior has changed. Inertial scrolling seems to have been enabled and it's awful. I can't find a way to disable it in the control panel.

Is there a way I can revert back to the old scrolling style I had?

I'm running windows 10 on a Dell Inspiron 5000. I can provide any other information if it's needed.

Comment: By restarted, do you mean you wiped the hard drive and started again or just shut it down?

Comment: Literally just turned it off and on

Comment: Try this, press windows key + R, type main.cpl and press enter. Look on the wheel tab, mine is set to 3 lines at a time.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have seen, turning off inertial scrolling is more often a setting for your particular hardware device, instead of a Windows setting. This is how I turned off inertial scrolling for my Dell Latitude E5440 with Dell Touchpad:

- Press windows key + R.
- Type main.cpl and press enter. This brings up Mouse Properties.
- Click, "Click to change Dell Touchpad settings".
- Click on the Gestures tab.
- Uncheck "Inertial scrolling"